# apache server takes very long time to establish a connection with ssl

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssl, apache-2.4, openssl

I am running apache-2.4.7 with Ubuntu 14.04, I have 2 cores, 2GB RAM on my server.

I have ssl enabled and activated on my website.

I usually push notifications to users, so sometimes maybe 150-200 users visit the website within 20 seconds.

The problem is, when i push a notification to users, or when i have big traffic the server responds very slowly for establishing a connection, i checked the cpu and memory usage and they both are working with less than 20% of their capabilities in the peak time.

I read data to my website from a json file on the same server and there are some mysql queries.

[The `htop` command when i have 200 online user on the website as Google Analytics claims](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9dUW.png)

Comment: Could you provide some specifics, in terms of "normal" SSL connection time versus the "very slow" connection times?  Are you measuring the time until the client has received the HTTP response, or are you measuring _just_ the SSL connection/handshake time?

Comment: Also give your SSL config. At very least your cipher list. Some are considerably slower than others. You can use the https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest to test your config but it does take a good bit of experience to understand what it's telling you.

Comment: Any particular reason why you're running an outdated version of Apache HTTP Server from late 2013? The latest version is 2.4.18.